# print logs with multicore

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, domc

Using foreach and doMC, is there a way to get `cat` and/or `message` to print to the screen when running in parallel? For example:

```
> library(foreach)
> 
> tmp <- foreach(i=1:3) %do% 
+   cat("sqrt(i) =", sqrt(i), "\n")
sqrt(i) = 1 
sqrt(i) = 1.414214 
sqrt(i) = 1.732051 

> 
> tmp <- foreach(i=1:3) %do% 
+   message("i^2 =", i^2, "\n")
i^2 =1

i^2 =4

i^2 =9

>       
> library(doMC)
> registerDoMC(2)
> 
> tmp <- foreach(i=1:3) %dopar% 
+   cat("sqrt(i) =", sqrt(i), "\n")
> 
> tmp <- foreach(i=1:3) %dopar% 
+   message("i^2 =", i^2, "\n")
>   
> sessionInfo()
R Under development (unstable) (2014-01-29 r64898)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[7] methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] doMC_1.3.2      iterators_1.0.6 foreach_1.4.1  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] codetools_0.2-8 compiler_3.1.0  tools_3.1.0
```

Thanks,

Max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, stdout from the workers isn't redirected when using foreach with the doMC backend, so output should be displayed unless you're using a GUI such as R.app on Mac OS X or Rgui on Windows. I just tried a quick test on my Mac, and it appears that RStudio also throws away stdout from the workers created by doMC/mclapply.

When executing R from a terminal, I see worker output on Mac OS X 10.7.5 using R 3.0.2 and "R Under development (unstable) (2014-02-13 r64986)". Since you're using a slightly older development build, it's possible that there was a problem that has been subsequently fixed.

You could try explicitly turning on output with the doMC-specific "silent" option:

```
> opts <- list(silent=FALSE)
> tmp <- foreach(i=1:3, .options.multicore=opts) %dopar% message('i^2 = ', i^2)
i^2 = 1
i^2 = 4
i^2 = 9
```

This causes mclapply to be called with `mc.silent=FALSE`. If that doesn't help, I suggest trying the latest development build which works for me.

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to work anymore with R 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) running on Mac OS X 10.10.5.

Comment: @CraigW Do you see output when executing `x <- mclapply(1:3, message, mc.cores=3)`? Are you executing the standard R interpreter from "Terminal"?

Comment: I take it back. Seems to show output when running R from terminal, but not from R.app GUI or RStudio. Is there any way to make this solution work in those environments?

Comment: @CraigW I don't know of a way to get stdout, stderr, or messages to be displayed in those environments. Using mclapply at all in those environments isn't recommended because of it's use of the fork system call.